# MySQL - Out of memory: Kill process 3046 (mysqld)

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, linux, my.cnf, mysqld

We run a MySQL (v5.6.17) dump backup every 4 hours, and today noticed:

```
Apr 19 20:09:30 mysql1 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 3046 (mysqld) score 970 or sacrifice child 
Apr 19 20:09:30 mysql1 kernel: Killed process 3046, UID 27, (mysqld) total-vm:12617880kB, anon-rss:7932424kB, file-rss:24kB 
Apr 19 20:09:30 mysql1 mysqld_safe: Number of processes running now: 0 
Apr 19 20:09:30 mysql1 mysqld_safe: mysqld restarted
```

See the entire log at: https://gist.github.com/nodesocket/daf77fb923b4bf6bef1f

The server is running 4 cpus and 16GB of memory with SSD disks. I thought the OS would swap instead of just crashing **mysqld** completely.

I suppose upgrading the server to 32GB of memory, would probably help, but wondering if we can optimize any settings in our `my.cnf` before we commit more physical resources and money.

```
############################################## 
# my.cnf 
############################################## 
[mysqld] 
datadir=/mysql/data 
socket=/mysql/mysqld.sock 
symbolic-links=0 
default-storage-engine=InnoDB 
slow_query_log=1 
long_query_time=2 
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql_slow.log 
expire_logs_days=30 
max_connections=50 

bind-address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
port=3306 
max_allowed_packet=4M 
net_retry_count=5 
max_connect_errors=100 
wait_timeout=14400 
connect_timeout=10 

open_files_limit=65535 
innodb_open_files=65535 
key_buffer_size=256M 
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M 
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M 
group_concat_max_len=16k 
max_sort_length=16k 
max_length_for_sort_data=16k 
query_cache_type=1 
query_cache_limit=1M 
query_cache_size=32M 
innodb_thread_concurrency=8 
thread_concurrency=8 
thread_cache_size=128 
thread_stack=1M 
read_buffer_size=1M 
join_buffer_size=1M 
sort_buffer_size=1M 
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M 
table_open_cache=32768 
table_definition_cache=65535 
tmp_table_size=33554432 
max_heap_table_size=33554432 
innodb_log_file_size=1024M 
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 
innodb_file_per_table=0 
log-warnings 
innodb_flush_neighbors=0 

user=mysql 
old_passwords=0 

[mysqld_safe] 
syslog 
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: `Apr 19 20:09:30 mysql1 kernel:  Free swap  = 0kB
Apr 19 20:09:30 mysql1 kernel:  Total swap = 0kB` - the kernel can't swap if it doesn't have swap space...

Comment: why would it not have swap? Plenty of disk space free.

Comment: Linux does not swap to random parts of your disk. You need to configure a swap device (or swap file) yourself.

Comment: I thought we created a swap, but `cat /proc/swaps` says otherwise, setting up a 8GB swap now.

Comment: @mat should provide it as an answer ;)